# Is there a difference between has_one on one model vs belongs_to on the other?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I understand that a belongs_to puts the foreign key on the declaring model, and a has_one puts it on the other model. Does that mean there is no difference in this example?

```
class Category
 belongs_to :blog
end

class Blog
end
```

---

```
class Blog
 has_one :category
end

class Category
end
```

The only thing I can see is that the second example's nomenclature makes a little more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

`belongs_to` expects the foreign key to be on its table whereas `has_one` expects it to be on the other:

```
# here the Category table will need to have a blog_id field
class Category
  belongs_to :blog
end

# the blog table won't need anything    
class Blog
  has_one :category
end
```

`has_one` under the hood is similar to `has_many` except it adds a LIMIT 1 clause to the sql statement when you query the table.

Answer (score 1):

The difference lies in the database, as you've noted.  The model with the `belongs_to` reference *must* contain the foreign key for the association.  When using `has_one`, it will expect to find a foreign key on the associated model.

Comment: Is there a reason to use one over the other, especially if it will be an optional relationship?

Comment: If one clearly is a child to another object, then I like `belongs_to`.  If they are just sibling objects (e.g. not a subclass) then `has_one` probably makes more sense.

Comment: I have a question. If I use `has_one` in a model `A` but not `belong_to` in the other model `B`, will `A` still be able to get the referenced `B` via `a.b`, since `B` does not contain the foreign key?

Comment: Answering my own comment question: No it doesn't work. `B` needs to contain the the foreign key (i.e. `belongs_to`) for it to work.